# Javascript remove child on click based on class

Tags: javascript

I'm making a basic list using vanilla javascript. I am able to add items, and change their class when they are clicked. Now, I want the items that have been selected (so their class has been changed) to be removed when they are clicked. At the bottom of the code, I am trying to loop through the list, then if the element in the list has the selected class, an event listener will remove the element when clicked, but this isn't working for me. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? (live demo: http://codepen.io/nicolaswilmot/pen/oXLgyq)

Here is the code:

```
var list = document.getElementById("theList"); // Get the list

// Add new item to top of list
function addItem(e) {
    var userTxt = document.getElementById("userInput"); // Get user text
    var newItem = document.createElement("li");    // Create new list item
    var itemTxt = document.createTextNode(userTxt.value); // Get the text for item
    newItem.appendChild(itemTxt);                  // Add text to list item
    list.insertBefore(newItem, list.firstChild);    // Put new item at top of list
    newItem.className = 'defaultItem';              // Set default class for li
    document.getElementById("userInput").value = ''; // Clear the input box
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent page from reloading when page is submitted
    // Changes list item class
    function changeClass () {
        newItem.className = 'selectedItem';
    }
    // Initialize array for list items
    listArray = [];
    // Loop through list, add items to array, update class and counter
    //      when items are clicked
    for (var i=0; i<list.children.length; i++) {
        listArray.push(newItem);
        listArray[i].addEventListener("click",changeClass);
        listArray[i].addEventListener("click",countStuff);
    }
}

var docForm = document.getElementById("theForm");  // Get the form element
docForm.addEventListener('submit',addItem,false);  // Call addItem function when form is submitted
docForm.addEventListener('submit',countStuff,false); //Call counter when form submitted

// Function for the list item counter
function countStuff() {
    // Get div container for counter
    var itemCount = document.getElementById("counter");
    // Get all list items that have not been selected (default class)
    var unselectedItems = document.querySelectorAll('li.defaultItem');
    //If more than one item, display plural "items"
    if (unselectedItems.length > 1) {
        itemCount.innerHTML = 'You still need '+unselectedItems.length+' items!';
    } else if (unselectedItems.length == 0) {
        itemCount.innerHTML = 'You have all items!';
    } else {
        itemCount.innerHTML = 'You still need '+unselectedItems.length+' item!';
    }
}

// Loop through the list
for (var i=0; i<list.children.length; i++) {
    // Remove items that are in selected state
    if (list.childNodes[i].className='selectedItem') {
        list.childNodes[i].addEventListener('click',function () {
            list.removeChild([i])},false);
    }
}
```

Comment: `removeChild` takes a DOM node as an argument, not an index: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placement of your code where you are trying to remove the element once it has the `selectedItem` class does not make sense, because that code will only run once on page load when the page has no items in the list.  Instead, in the same function where you add the `selectedItem` class, you can bind an event listener to that DOM element that removes it from the list on the next click. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOKEzz

```
function changeClass () {
    newItem.className = 'selectedItem';
    //Remove it on click!
    newItem.addEventListener('click',function () {
        list.removeChild(newItem)
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: Yep, a bit simpler! Haha.